# Probability of selling the same items again in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I need to know the probability of selling similar items together, based on a sales history formatted like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({"sale_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
              "item": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "D", "E", "C", "B"],
              "qty": [1, 4, 3, 2, 8, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9]})

sale_id Item    Qty
1       A       1
1       B       4
1       C       3
2       A       2
2       C       8
3       A       3
3       D       6
3       E       5
3       C       12
4       B       9
```

I want to build a matrix like this:

[image: Correlation Matrix]

I have tried pivoting the data frame and using a the pd.DataFrame.corr() with a custom callable, but i ran out of RAM by calling:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index = "sales_id", columns = "item")
```

The actual dataframe that I'm using is 700,000 lines long and have 20,000 different items.

Comment: Would you like to add the source of your dataframe so people don't have to manually re-create it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot, the data frame contains sensitive data, but I edited the question with the code to generate the data frame I used as an example.

Comment: Easy. Have you done anything so far or are you completely stuck?

Comment: I've tried pivoting the items to the columns and then iterating through the dataframe counting how many times A and B happen on the same sale_id. But I ran out of RAM just by pivoting.

Comment: This is a good thing to include in your question. You need to explain that atm your main concern is the space complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question again to better explain my problem.

Comment: A faster way of doing your pivot would be: `df.set_index(['sale_id', 'item']).unstack()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set out to find a purely Pandas way of doing things, and ended up also optimizing Pavel's method quite a lot.

Before anything else I do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"sale_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
              "item": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "D", "E", "C", "B"],
              "qty": [1, 4, 3, 2, 8, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9]})
df.drop('qty', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Then, timing/memory tracing begins:

1. **Pandas only method:**

```
values = df.groupby('sale_id')['item'].agg(lambda x: [*combinations(sorted(x), 2)]).explode().value_counts()
denom = df['sale_id'].nunique()
output = (values/denom).reindex(combinations(df['item'].unique(), 2), fill_value=0)
output
```

Output, Timing and Memory Usage:

```
(A, B)    0.25
(A, C)    0.75
(A, D)    0.25
(A, E)    0.25
(B, C)    0.25
(B, D)    0.00
(B, E)    0.00
(C, D)    0.25
(C, E)    0.25
(D, E)    0.25
Name: item, dtype: float64

475 µs ± 13.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

(End, Peek) Memory: (5442, 16440)
```

2. **Optimized version of Pavel's Method:**

The only differences are extracting just `item` from the groupby, so a `Series` is produced rather than a `DataFrame`, using `agg` instead of `transform`, and not using a `set` since it's not necessary after `agg`.

```
grp = df.groupby('sale_id')['item'].agg(lambda x: ''.join(x))
purchases = grp.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)).unique()
unique_items = df.item.unique()
res = {}
for c in combinations(unique_items, 2):
    c = set(c)
    res[frozenset(c)] = 0
    for i in purchases:
        if c.intersection(i) == c:
            res[frozenset(c)] += 1
for k, v in res.items():
    res[k] = v / purchases.shape[0]
res
```

Output, Timing and Memory Usage:

```
{frozenset({'A', 'B'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'A', 'C'}): 0.75,
 frozenset({'A', 'D'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'A', 'E'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'B', 'C'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'B', 'D'}): 0.0,
 frozenset({'B', 'E'}): 0.0,
 frozenset({'C', 'D'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'C', 'E'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'D', 'E'}): 0.25}

276 µs ± 6.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

(End, Peek) Memory: (7643, 19402)
```

3. **Original Method:**

```
grp = df.groupby('sale_id').transform(lambda x: ''.join(x))
purchases = grp['item'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(set(x))).unique()
unique_items = df.item.unique()
res = {}
for c in combinations(unique_items, 2):
    c = set(c)
    res[frozenset(c)] = 0
    for i in purchases:
        if c.intersection(i) == c:
            res[frozenset(c)] += 1
for k, v in res.items():
    res[k] = v / purchases.shape[0]
res
```

Timing and Memory Usage:

```
1.01 ms ± 30.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

(End, Peek) Memory: (15847, 27630)
```

Methods used were `%timeit` in a Jupyter Notebook, and `tracemalloc` for memory tracing.

Comment: @pavel Found two more changes, cutting time another 50%~

Comment: Actually your pandas-based solution seems to be the best to solve the memory issues that the OP was facing, although on the balance of performance/memory solution 2 is of course the best. The biggest issue is that OP has 2000 products so it's approximately 2e6 different combinations of size 2. So it will take a bit of time.

Comment: I didn't get any difference with this small dataset, but sometimes performance can be improved by changing string columns with a lot of repetition to categorical type. Aka `df.item = df.item.astype('category')`, this also pretty much always lowers memory usage of a DataFrame~

Comment: Interestingly, in my data frame, with 20000 different items, the 1st method using only Pandas took just 1 minute to run, whereas the other methods were still stuck in the loop for several minutes. I guess Pandas might have some optimization running behind the hood.

Comment: @RenanKlehm. yes, that is rather strange. It's likely that the performance improvement comes from executing the code outside the Python inerpreter and primarily in C which pandas would do. Overall algorithm complexities are roughly the same, but pandas working in C behind the hood offers a significant boost.

Comment: Hello @BeRT2me Any idea why I get "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" at line 'for c in combinations(unique_items, 2)' when I try the modified Pavel's method?

Comment: @Very_new_to_this because at some point you made a `list` named `combinations` that overwrote the `combinations` function imported from `itertools`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the standard algorithm for collaborative filtering would go something like:

- first you need to group your data by sale_id and combine the values in the item column.
- Then for each group you need to create a set of items that were bought together.
- Then finally you need to create every possible combination of existing items as a set and do the intersection with your actual item sets

This is what it all looks for me. This should have a linear space complexity and I'm sure it can be improved still but it can work.

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"sale_id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
              "item": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "D", "E", "C", "B"],
              "qty": [1, 4, 3, 2, 8, 3, 6, 5, 12, 9]})

# we don't care about quantity
df = df.loc[:, ['sale_id', 'item']]

# Get all the unique sets of items sold
grp = df.groupby('sale_id').transform(lambda x: ''.join(x))
purchases = grp['item'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(set(x))).unique()

# create all possible two-item pairs, then iterate over them
# adding 1 to the value of dictionary when the purchase
# matches the combination
unique_items = df.item.unique()
res = {}

for c in combinations(unique_items, 2):
    c = set(c)
    res[frozenset(c)] = 0
    for i in purchases:
        if c.intersection(i) == c:
            res[frozenset(c)] += 1

# get percentages
for k, v in res.items():
    res[k] = v / purchases.shape[0]
```

Output:

```
{frozenset({'A', 'B'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'A', 'C'}): 0.75,
 frozenset({'A', 'D'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'A', 'E'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'B', 'C'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'B', 'D'}): 0.0,
 frozenset({'B', 'E'}): 0.0,
 frozenset({'C', 'D'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'C', 'E'}): 0.25,
 frozenset({'D', 'E'}): 0.25}
```

Comment: The code is running the first loop for about 20 minutes now, but it doesn't look like it is going to exhaust my RAM, accepting your answer just by the explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: @RenanKlehm, the time complexity of this algorithm is rather poor but generally the time complexity for collaborative filtering is pretty bad.

Comment: @pavel I outline in my answer a small change in your answer that could speed up the process significantly~