# Error in an accepted answer: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

In [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72223091/probability-of-selling-the-same-items-again-in-a-pandas-dataframe/72224580), there is this problem I am trying to solve. There is a very detailed answer which for some reason does not work for me and gives

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

df=

```
index       sale_id      item
33337606    02234563    389699
29350189    02234520    230153
5002610     02234403    P79927
3357151     02235866    I25240
29351311    02234520    230155
...         ...         ...
```

```
grp = df.groupby('sale_id')['item'].agg(lambda x: ''.join(x))
purchases = grp.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x)).unique()
unique_items = df.item.unique()
res = {}
for c in combinations(unique_items, 2):
    c = set(c)
    res[frozenset(c)] = 0
    for i in purchases:
        if c.intersection(i) == c:
            res[frozenset(c)] += 1
for k, v in res.items():
    res[k] = v / purchases.shape[0]
res
```

Comment: Sounds like you assigned a list to something you shouldn't have, but we can't tell from this. Post a [mcve] and the complete, exact error message, including full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

My bad completely, sorry guys. I had not imported combinations.

from itertools import combinations

Comment: As mentioned in a comment, you must have previously assigned a list value to the name `combinations`, or you would have simply gotten a `NameError` for the undefined name `combinations` rather than a `TypeError`.